# When opening scraped link in browser it appears broken, after refreshing page, it works

Tags: r, rvest

The following code, does quite a few things, but mainly it enters the archive of the webpage time dot mk. and extracts a large number of links across a 7 month period, after which I clear the data for the links from the webpages I want (time dot mk compiles news from many different webpages):

```
library(rvest)
y <- NULL
for (week in 22:49) {
firstdate = paste0("http://www.time.mk/week/2016/", week)
frontpage = read_html(firstdate) %>%
html_nodes("a") %>%
html_attr("href")
justweeks <- frontpage[grepl("^week.*", frontpage)]
mark = "http://www.time.mk/"
weeklinks = paste0(mark, justweeks)
weeklinks = unique(weeklinks)
y <- rbind (y, weeklinks)
allothers <- unlist (lapply(y, function(i) {
read_html(i) %>%
html_nodes(".other_articles") %>%
html_attr("href") %>%
paste0()}))}
print(allothers)
fullinks = paste0 (mark, allothers, sep = "")
print(fullinks)
#all primary links .other articles obtained ->  need to obtain the 
.otherarticles 
alllinks <- unlist (lapply (fullinks, function (i) {
read_html(i) %>%
html_nodes("h1 a") %>%
html_attr("href") %>%
paste0()}))
print(alllinks)
#all links obtained -> try to sort data that I need now -> a1 
a1onLinks <- alllinks[grepl(".*a1on*", alllinks)]
print(a1onLinks)
#obtaining text -> not there just yet 
a1ontext <- lapply(a1onLinks, function (i) {
try(
read_html(i) %>%
html_nodes ("p") %>%
html_text() %>%
paste0(collapse=""))})
```

The problem is that once I've retrieved only the necessary links, once I try to **scrape** only the text from them, R returns an error, namely:

Error in open.connection(x, "rb") :
Unrecognized or bad HTTP Content or Transfer-Encoding

As far as I can tell, this is because when I try to open the links in my browser they are broken and return something like this for (almost!) every link:
Wd�R$���&��)/��Y�f�R�

After refreshing the link in my browser 5-6 times, it loads normally.

The retrieved links look something like this:

[965] "http://a1on.mk/wordpress/archives/655118"
[967] "http://a1on.mk/wordpress/archives/654641"

I'm really unsure as to what the problem here is and I am wondering how I could tell R to run the code for extracting text until it can extract it. Functions like try and tryCatch have not turned out useful here.

Comment: I'm not sure yet, whether it's relevant, but are you using Safari as your default browser?

Comment: No, I'm using Chrome.

Comment: I think it doesn't matter anyway. I have no idea what the could be